# Singling out one period in an entire signal and plotting its Fourier transform phase and magnitude

Tags: arrays, matlab, signal-processing, fft, phase

SO I have an ECG signal that I have to single out only one period from it and find its phase and magnitude. I have this so far:

```
x1 = 3.5*ecg(2700);
y1 = sgolayfilt(kron(ones(1,13),x1),0,21);

n = (1:60000)';      %SOURCE OF THE PROBLEM. CANT FIND CORRECT N value to plug

mhb = y1(n);
ts = 0.00025;
t = [ts: ts: 7.5];
%plot (t, mhb)
%axis([2.95 3.626 -3 3.3])       %for one of the periods (cheat method) but its ok

f = [-(3*n/2):1:(3*n/2)-1]*(1/(3*ts*n));
f = [-(3*n/2):1:(3*n/2)-1]*(1/(3*ts*n));

Xf = fft(mhb);


subplot(211), plot(t, fftshift(abs(Xf))),axis([2.95 3.626 0 115]), grid 
subplot(212), plot(t, fftshift(angle(Xf))), axis([2.95 3.626 -3 4]), grid
```

The problem is that for this signal the frequency in Hz is defined by this equation:  f = [-(3*n/2):1:(3*n/2)-1]*(1/(3*ts*n)); and trying to get the n value appropraite so it dosent exceed the matrix value seems impossible. The only hint is that if N is 30000, then add 2N extra zeros before the fft (not quite sure what that means). However it is the n value that is causing the problem. Whoever can figure this, I will be forever grateful to him/her.

P.s. I have tried doing 30000 + add 2(4 zeros) = overflow and computer crash. Dont do that option :P